# Cypress Incorrect Behavior with Quasar Virtual Scroll Table and Sticky Header: NOT solved by { scrollBehavior: false }

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, quasar-framework, virtualscroll

I am using [Quasar 2](https://quasar.dev/) to create a virtual-scroll table with a sticky header. The table loads results dynamically and the default number of initially loaded results is 100.

The table header is sticky and contains the column names, and a search input for some of the columns. Cypress has successfully tested user input and result output on these header inputs.

My problem comes in where I want to interact with buttons contained in certain table cells.

The table is essentially a container with several widgets where the user can interact to adjust data. This means that for one of the columns, each cell has certain buttons based on the information contained in that row. Cypress is able to find those buttons, and even succesfully executes a click action on any given button index in the set. Example:

```
cy.dataCy('edit-info-button').eq(3).click()
```

However, my problem is that cypress scrolls whatever button it clicks on, way up underneath the sticky header of my virtual-scroll table. **I must point out that I have already disabled `scrollBehavior` globally (in cypress.json) and when that didn't work, I also disabled it locally in my function.** However, I think that the virtual-scroll table behaves differently and cannot be governed by this config parameter.

I don't spot this under the caveats section of the [Quasar Cypress testing documentation](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar-testing/blob/dev/packages/e2e-cypress/README.md).

Comment: First, I would make sure in some way that the browser under Cypress got all necessary styles like overflow: scroll/auto (and scroll-behavior). Then I'd try to play with [scrollRestoration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/scrollRestoration) and [overflow-anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor)... hope this helps